# Save user chosen background image using cookies in javascript across webpages

Tags: javascript, image, cookies, background, customization

Okay so I'm trying to save this function using cookies, and I can't seem to get the cookies to interact with the function.

```
var backImage = new Array(); 

backImage[0] = "dotPattern.png";
backImage[1] = "stripesPattern.png";
backImage[2] = "boxPattern.png";
backImage[3] = "";

function changeBGImage(whichImage){
    document.body.background = backImage[whichImage];

 }
```

Can you let me know what I'm doing wrong or what else I have to do. I've got the image files and the html all in the same folder. Let me know if you need anything else and I can put it up here too.

Thank you very much for any help you're able to offer

Here is the page the cookies are meant to be used on:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>

<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="customise.js"></script>


    <title>Vitalita - My Profile</title>
    <div id="Logo">
    <a href="home.html"><img id="logo" src="LogoSmall.png" height=125px border="0" alt="Image not found"></img></a>
    </div>

<body>


            <header>

        <nav id="top">
            <ul  id="menu">


                <li><a class="nav" id="about" href="#">about</a>

                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a class="aboutMenu" href="aboutus.html">about us</a></li>
                        <li><a class="aboutMenu" href="contactus.html">contact us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>

                <li><a class="nav" id="health" href="#">health</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a class="healthMenu" href="#">information</a></li>
                        <li><a class="healthMenu" href="#">exercise</a></li>
                        <li><a class="healthMenu" href="recipes.html">recipes</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a class="nav" id="media" href="#">media</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a class="mediaMenu" href="articles.html">articles</a></li>
                        <li><a class="mediaMenu" href="#">videos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a class="nav" id="tools" href="#">tools</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a class="toolMenu" href="BMI.html">BMI calculator</a></li>
                        <li><a class="toolMenu" href="#">measurements</a></li>
                        <li><a class="toolMenu" href="#">exercise generator</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a class="nav" id="social" href="#">social</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a class="socialMenu" href="social.html">social media</a></li>
                        <li><a class="socialMenu" href="#">games</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a class="nav" id="account" href="registration.html">account</a>
                <img src="icon.png" height=19px id="icon"></img>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a class="accountMenu" href="#">my profile</a></li>
                        <li><a class="accountMenu" href="#">my progress</a></li>
                        <li><a class="accountMenu" href="#">my favourites</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </header>


    <body>

     <a href="http://instagram.com/vitalita_aus"><img id=insta src="insta.png" height=50px></img></a>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Vitalita/936304006385343"><img id=fb src="fb.png" height=50px></img></a>
        <a href="http://twitter.com/vitalia_aus"><img id=twit src="twit.png" height=50px></img></a>

<section id="feature">


<a href="javascript:changeBGImage(0);" id="dotButton">Dot Pattern</a>
<a href="javascript:changeBGImage(1)" id="dotButton">Stripes Pattern</a>
<a href="javascript:changeBGImage(2)" id="dotButton">Box Pattern</a>
<a href="javascript:changeBGImage(3)" id="dotButton">Default</a>



</section>

<hr id="first">
<footer>
<div class="Foot">
    <div id="footHome">
    <bold>Home</bold>
        <ul class="sitemap">
            <li><a class="links" href="home.html">Home Page</a>
        </ul>
    </div>  
    <div id="footAbout">
    <bold>About</bold>
        <ul class="sitemap">
            <li><a class="links" href="aboutus.html">About Us</a> 
                <ul class="sitemap">
                    <li><a class="links" href="">Style Guide</a>
                    <li><a class="links" href="">Evaluation Plan</a>
                </ul>   
            <li><a class="links" href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
            <li><a class="links" href="feedbackform.html">Feedback</a>
            <li><a class="links" href="helpdesk.html">FAQ</a>
            <li><a class="links" href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footHealth">
        <bold>Health</bold>
        <ul class="sitemap">
            <li><a class="links" href="#">Information</a>
            <li><a class="links" href="#">Exercise</a>
            <li><a class="links" href="recipes.html">Recipes</a>        
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footMedia">
        <bold>Media</bold>
        <ul class="sitemap">
            <li><a class="links" href="#">Articles</a>
            <li><a class="links" href="#">Videos</a>
            <li><a class="links" href="#">Games</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footTools">
        <bold>Tools</bold>
        <ul class="sitemap">
            <li><a class="links" href="BMI.html">BMI calculator</a>
            <li><a class="links" href="#">Measurements</a>
            <li><a class="links" href="#">Exercise generator</a>        
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footSocial">
        <bold>Social</bold>
        <ul class="sitemap">
            <li><a class="links" href="social.html">Social Media</a>
            <li><a class="links" href="#">Games</a>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footAccount">
        <bold>Account</bold>
        <ul class="sitemap">
            <li><a class="links" href="#">My Profile</a>
            <li><a class="links" href="#">My Progress</a>
            <li><a class="links" href="#">My Favourites</a>     
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <hr id="second">
</footer>

<div id="copy">
Copyright &copy; Vitalita 2014. All Rights Reserved. 
<div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But where do you use cookies? I can't see anything like this here.

Comment: @dds hey I just put up the page where the cookies are meant to be implanted on to change the background colour

Answer (score 0):

To use cookies you need to save and load them explicitly. You can find how to do this in javascript in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie) question.